# Unable to boot normally sometimes (Initifram appears)

Tags: boot

So I downloaded Ubuntu, everything fine, but in the 24 hours passed, this initifram has appeared twice 
http://i.imgsafe.org/4bf525efea.jpg

Indeed I use `fsck /dev/sda1` to repair it. After second repair my hard-drive wasn't modifiable at all because I "wasn't the owner". Any idea how to fix it? I can reinstall Ubuntu but this is like the 3rd time I do because of this issue so I seek how to prevent it as well as fix it in future (and fix the hard-drive read-only thing as well.

Thankyou very much!

As for my info, here it is:

```
System: Host: Azarias12-Musashi Kernel: 4.8.0-39-generic x86_64 (64 bit) 
Desktop: Unity Distro: Machine: System: Sony (portable) 
product: SVE14A27CLS v: C60BUH5N Mobo: Sony model: VAIO Bios: American Megatrends v: R0201V5 date: 12/20/2012 
CPU: Dual core Intel Core i5-3210M (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB 
clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 2899 MHz 2: 3072 MHz 3: 2899 MHz 4: 3007 MHz GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI 
Intel Ivybridge Mobile GLX Version: 3.0 
Mesa 17.1.0-devel Audio: Card Intel 7 Series/C210 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel 
Sound: ALSA v: k4.8.0-39-generic Network: Card-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath9k IF: wlp2s0 
state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: a4:17:31:f1:d7:5d Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: r8169 
IF: enp4s0 state: down mac: f0:bf:97:ea:dc:df Drives: HDD Total Size: 1750.4GB (47.8% used) 
ID-1: /dev/sda model: N/A size: 750.2GB ID-2: /dev/sdb model: N/A size: 1000.2GB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 672G used: 90G (15%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 ID-2: swap-1 size: 17.04GB used: 0.00GB (0%) 
fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5 RAID: No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present 
Sensors: None detected - is lm-sensors installed and configured? 
Info: Processes: -1 Uptime: 6 min Memory: 2220.1/15919.8MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Comment: Here are more pictures of the issued (happened again!) i.imgsafe.org/4df6abf404.jpg i.imgsafe.org/4dfe80f489.jpg i.imgsafe.org/4df7aa8e3a.jpg  Also, a side note that this third "repair" did changed the hard-drive issue I had, now I can edit it again! But still would like to know how to avoid it please :(

Comment: I thought it did but problem is back hard-drive issue is back :(

Comment: Seems the hard-drive issue happens whenenver I try to run Steam... Any idea why?

Comment: Help anyone? =(